# How do I read in wav files in .gz?

Tags: python, gzip

I am learning machine learning and data analysis on `wav` files.
I know if I have `wav` files directly I can do something like this to read in the data

```
import librosa

mono, fs = librosa.load('./small_data/time_series_audio.wav', sr = 44100)
```

Now I'm given a gz-file `"music_feature_extraction_test.tar.gz"`
I'm not sure what to do now.

I tried:

```
with gzip.open('music_train.tar.gz', 'rb') as f:
    for files in f : 
        mono, fs = librosa.load(files, sr = 44100)
```

but it gives me:

`TypeError: lstat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str`

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things going on:

- The file you are given is a gzipped-compressed tarball. Take a look at the `tarfile` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html), it can read gzip-compressed files directly. You'll get an iterator over it's members, each of which is an individual file.
- AFAIKS `librosa` can't read from an in-memory buffer so you have to unpack the tar-members to temporary files. The `tempfile`-[module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) is your friend here, a `NamedTemporaryFile` will provide you with a self-deleting file that you can uncompress to and provide to `librosa`.

You probably want to implement this as a simple generator function that takes the tarfile-name as it's input, iterates over it's members and `yield`s what `librosa.load()` provides you. That way everything gets cleaned up automatically.

The basic loop would therefore be

1. Open the tarball using the `tarfile`-module. For each member
2. Get a new temporary file using `NamedTemporaryFile`. Copy the content of the tarball-member to that file. You may want to use `shutil.copyfileobj` to avoid reading the entire wav-file into memory before writing it to disk.
3. The `NamedTemporaryFile` has a filename-attribute. Pass that to `librosa.open`.
4. `yield` the return value of `librosa.open` to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PySoundFile to read from the compressed file.
https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.0/#virtual-io

```
import soundfile

with gzip.open('music_train.tar.gz', 'rb') as gz_f:
    for file in gz_f : 
        fs, mono = soundfile.read(file, samplerate=44100)
```

Maybe you should also check if you need to resample the data before processing it with librosa:
https://librosa.github.io/librosa/ioformats.html#read-specific-formats